# Working around overloading restriction (implementing a trait for several types)

Tags: scala, overloading

I know it's not possible to overload methods which differ only in the return type. But I wonder if there are any smart strategies to deal efficiently with this situation:

```
trait Reader[A] { def read(in: java.io.DataInput): A }

trait B; trait C

def doSomethingB()(implicit r: Reader[B]) = ()
def doSomethingC()(implicit r: Reader[C]) = ()

trait MultiReader extends Reader[B] with Reader[C] { // not possible
  implicit me = this

  doSomethingB()
  doSomethingC()
}
```

By smart and efficient I mean, I would like to avoid clutter and unnecessary inner class generations like this:

```
trait MultiReader {
  implicit object RB extends Reader[B] { ... }
  implicit object RC extends Reader[C] { ... }

  doSomethingB()
  doSomethingC()
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a partial solution. I have been re-reading [this gist](https://gist.github.com/89c9b47a91017973a35f) by Miles Sabin in the last days which appeared very inspiring. So I can do the following:

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U]  = T with Tagged[U]

trait Reader[A] { def read(in: java.io.DataInput @@ A): A }
```

And then this works:

```
trait MultiReader {
  def read(in: java.io.DataInput @@ B): B
  def read(in: java.io.DataInput @@ C): C
}
```

But the inheritance is somewhat still broken:

```
trait MultiReader extends Reader[B] with Reader[C]
```

(fails with `"self-type MultiReader does not conform to Reader[B]'s selftype Reader[B]"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still instantiates a `Function1` plus an anonymous `Reader` for each type parameter required, but at least it is syntactically more concise:

```
object Reader {
  implicit def fromFun[A](implicit fun: java.io.DataInput => A): Reader[A] =
    new Reader[A] { def read(in: java.io.DataInput): A = fun(in) }
}
trait Reader[A] { def read(in: java.io.DataInput): A }

def doSomethingB()(implicit r: Reader[B]): Unit = println(r.read(null))
def doSomethingC()(implicit r: Reader[C]): Unit = println(r.read(null))

trait MultiReader {
  implicit def readB(in: java.io.DataInput): B = new B { override def toString = "B" }
  implicit def readC(in: java.io.DataInput): C = new C { override def toString = "C" }

   doSomethingB()
   doSomethingC()
}

new MultiReader {} // --> B, C
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that Scala doesn't allow one to implement a generic trait more than once, even if the type parameters differ. Interestingly, although calling into the tagged version works correctly (I can deliberately call `read` with the input tagged `B` or `C`), it fails when using structural types, like this:

```
def doSomethingB()(implicit r: { def read(in: java.io.DataInput @@ B): B }) = ()
def doSomethingC()(implicit r: { def read(in: java.io.DataInput @@ C): C }) = ()
```

There is a dispatch bug here, and both will call into reading `C`.

---

If there is a constraint that `B` and `C` are within *one class hierarchy*, an idea is to use bounds:

```
sealed trait B; trait C extends B

trait UpDownReader[Up, Down] {
  def read[A >: Down <: Up : Manifest](in: java.io.DataInput): A
}

class MultiReader(implicit mfx: Manifest[X], mfy: Manifest[Y])
  extends UpDownReader[X, Y] {

  def read[A >: Y <: X](in: java.io.DataInput)(implicit mf: Manifest[A]): A =
     (if (mf == mfx) new X {} else new Y {}).asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

This works:

```
val m = new MultiReader
m.read[B](null)
m.read[C](null)
```

However, I would call this neither elegant nor efficient, given the 'dynamic' comparison of the manifests and then the ugly cast to `A`.